# Get an id of the active a link

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the id of the activated link of a element.

```
<div class="tabs">
 <a class="title active" id="tab-1"></a>
 <a class="title" id="tab-2"></a>
 <a class="title" id="tab-3"></a>
</div> 
<div id="close"></div>

<script>
$('#close').click(function() {
   alert($('.tabs').find('a:active').attr('id'));
}
<\scripts>
```

The alert returns 'undefined'. What's not right with this?

Comment: Change class=".tabs" to class="tabs"

Comment: change <div class="tabs">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
 alert($('.active').attr('id'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
alert($(".tabs a").find('a:active').attr('id'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Please update this with your jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#close').click(function() {
    alert($(this).parent().find('a.active').attr('id'));
     alert($('.tabs').find('a.active').attr('id'));
     }
    )

       });
```

If it solve your problems accept it